# What causes a full request on this page?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, glassfish-3

Consider the following jsf page:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="SessionStartDialog">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    <h:outputLabel
                        value="Enter your username:" 
                        for="UsernameField"/>
                </td>
                <td class="input">
                    <h:inputText 
                        id="UsernameField"
                        value="#{login.username}"
                        validator="#{login.validateUsername}"
                        tabindex="1">
                        <f:ajax render="SelectWorkingSetListbox
                                StartSessionButton UsernameMessage" />
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:message 
                        id="UsernameMessage"
                        for="UsernameField" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    <h:outputLabel
                        value="Choose a working-set:" 
                        for="SelectWorkingSetListbox"/>
                </td>
                <td class="input">
                    <h:selectOneMenu
                        id="SelectWorkingSetListbox"
                        tabindex="2"
                        disabled="#{!login.showWorkingSets}"
                        value="#{login.selectedWorkingSetName}">
                        <f:selectItems 
                            value="#{login.workingSetNames}"/>
                        <f:ajax />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h:commandButton 
            id="StartSessionButton"
            styleClass="StartSessionButton"
            disabled="#{!login.showWorkingSets}"
            value="Start Session" 
            tabindex="3"
            action="#{login.startSession}" >
            <f:ajax execute="@form"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Something in there causes Safari to report an error that ajax and full requests are being mixed. I do not understand why, as all components that cause requests contain `<f:ajax>`-tags. What is the problem here?

**Update**:

I have created a minimal example that triggers this error:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <f:ajax render="TextField">
            <h:inputText value="#{theBean.text}" />                
        </f:ajax>
        <h:outputText id="TextField" value="#{theBean.text}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

`theBean` is a simple view-scoped bean and `text` a property of type `String`. For some reason this triggers the following message in Safari 5.1:

> httpError: The Http Transport returned a 0 status code.  This is
>   usually the result of mixing ajax and full requests.  This is usually
>   undesired, for both performance and data integrity reasons.

**Update 2** The reason for this seem to be that hitting `enter` inside the `input`-field always triggers a full form submit. I have no idea how to prevent this. As shown in the first example, I want to user to enter a username, and then the other components of the form get enabled (only if the username is known). How would I implement this correctly?

Comment: On which component's event does the full postback occur? On button click or on the other components?

Comment: @Nikhil: That is my question. I do not know. I get the message when I enter something in the `h:inputText`-component.

Comment: Does it only happen in Safari? What about other browsers?

Comment: @Zenzen: Firefox produces the same message. I do not have other browser available for testing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd capture the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the `<form>` and instead trigger `onchange` on the `<input>` element where this key was pressed.

```html
<h:form onkeydown="enterToChange(event)">
    ...
</h:form>
```

with

```js
function enterToChange(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.target.tagName != 'textarea') {
    event.stopPropagation(); // Don't bubble up.
    event.preventDefault();  // Prevent default behaviour (submitting the form).
    event.target.onchange(); // Trigger onchange where key was actually pressed.
  }
}
```

Note that this ignores the enter key on textareas where you'd of course like to keep the intended behaviour (inserting a new line).

You could if necessary add an extra check to see if the submit button is not `disabled` and if that is the case, then just let the event go.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is that, in the absence of an `<h:commandButton>` (in the first example it is initially disabled, in the second example, there is none), pressing return will trigger a submit of the entire form, causing the error shown in the question.

The resolution for now is to have the `<h:commandButton>` always enabled. Since it is `<f:ajax>`-enabled, this will prevent a full submit.

**P.S.:** I posted this answer to show a possible solution for others. I would still like to know if there is a better solution (one that does not require the presence of a `<h:commandButton>`).